# Looping through all of the days within a Unix Timestamp range in PHP

Tags: php, loops, strtotime

Say you're given two Unix Timestamps like this:

```
$startDate = 1330581600;
$endDate = 1333170000;
```

I want to loop through each day in that range and output it something like this:

```
Start Loop
   Day Time Stamp: [Timestamp for the day within that loop]
End Loop
```

I've tried looking for some type of function to do this, but i'm not sure if it's even possible.

Answer (score 8):

As I love DateTime, DateInterval and DatePeriod, here is my solution:

```
$start = new DateTime();
$end   = new DateTime();

$start->setTimestamp(1330581600);
$end->setTimestamp(1333170000);

$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($period as $dt) {
  echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

This seems to be confusing at first, but it's a very logical approach.

With [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) you are defining a start and an end of a period with an interval of 1 day (look up the format at [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)), and then you can just iterate over it.
Finally, in every iteration you get back a [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) on which you can use `DateTime::format()`

Comment: +1 for using the `DateTime` family of classes, since they're pretty freaking awesome.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($t = $start; $t < $end; $t = strtotime('+1 day', $t)) {
    ...
}
```